# How to append a character in price column in a pandas object

Tags: python, pandas, string, append

I would like to append a coma "," just before the 2 last digit of the object, for example I have :

4000000
and I want :
40000,00

with all the ressources I think it's something it should be something like that:

```
car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].str.append(",", ).astype(int)
```

So what should I put in the append I am not able to figure, if someone have an idea please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to maintain the data-type as an int and display the cents values to the right of a comma or would you like to transform the price into a string?

Comment: if you want to keep it a string, then you would want to use apply: car_sales["Price"] = car_sales["Price"].apply(lambda x: ','.join([str(x)[:-2], str(x)[-2:]]) if len(str(x))>2 else str(x))

Comment: I am sorry yes I didn't precise but I would link to carry it as an int type and display the cents values please